# how to access kibana url in aws Elasticsearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I followed a tutorial to create a new domain in the elastic search service. I created a policy as follows,

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "es:ESHttpDelete","es:ESHttpGet","es:ESHttpHead",
                "es:ESHttpPost","es:ESHttpPut"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

then i created a role for a lambda to access elastic service. later i plan to call elastic search from lambda. here is my role ARN

```
arn:aws:iam::566879691663:role/myRole
```

and then for elastic search domain ,  I assigned "public access" for  network configuration. and for access policy, I selected "custom access policy" and added my above role. the access policy json looks like below

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::566879691663:role/myRole*"
        ]
      },
      "Action": [
        "es:*"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-east-1:566879691663:domain/mydomain/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

once the domain is up and running, when I click on the kibana url generated, I get the following json response in the browser. how can i access this via browser ?

```
{"message : " user : anonymous is not authorized to perform this action..."}
```

also, to be able to access/upload programatically, using AWS4AUTH, which requires aws access and secret key, how to I generate those? do i need to create a user and assign the above policy to the user?

Comment: Have you selected "Allow open access to the domain." for the access policy? What are your ES policies?

Comment: Can you update the question with relevant info. Comments are not well suited for code, such as iam policies. Also which "access key/private key" are you referenting?

Comment: @Marcin- sorry, i'm new to this site. I have edited my question.